# How to add custom methods to eloquent model in a way we can chain them?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

What I want is add methods to eloquent models so I can chain them, for example:

```php
class MovieResolver
{
    public function getMoviesFeaturingToday(array $args)
    {
        // Movie is an Eloquent model

        $movie = (new Movie())
            ->getMoviesFeaturingTodayOnTheater($args['movieTheaterId'])
            ->getBySessionCategory($args['sessioncategory']);

        // And keep doing some operations if necessary, like the code below.
        // I cannot call the get() method unless I finish my operations.

        return $movie->whereDate('debut', '<=', Carbon::today())
            ->orderBy('debut', 'desc')
            ->get();
    }
}
```

But adding these methods to the model:

```php
class Movie extends Model
{
    public function getMoviesFeaturingTodayOnTheater($theaterId)
    {
        return $this->whereHas(
            'sessions.entries.movieTheaterRoom',
            function ($query) use ($theaterId) {
                $query->where('movie_theater_id', $theaterId);
            }
        );
    }

    public function getBySessionCategory($sessionCategory)
    {
        return $this->whereHas(

        );
    }


}
```

Results in the following error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getMoviesFeaturingTodayOnTheater()

But why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check out query scopes - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done using [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#query-scopes). So try this in your model instead:

```
public function scopeMoviesFeaturingTodayOnTheater($query, $theaterId)
{
    return $query->whereHas(
           'sessions.entries.movieTheaterRoom',
            function ($query) use ($theaterId) {
                $query->where('movie_theater_id', $theaterId);
            }
        );
}

public function scopeBySessionCategory($query, $sessionCategory)
{
     return $query->whereHas(
        // ...
     );
}
```

Then to use it you do:

```
Movie::moviesFeaturingTodayOnTheater($args['movieTheaterId'])
    ->bySessionCategory($args['sessioncategory']);;
```